# No "accept merge request" button with developer level access

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm not seeing an "Accept Merge Request" button in gitlab despite having "Developer" level access. Instead there is this message:

```
Ready to be merged automatically

Ask someone with write access to this repository to merge this request.
```

According to the documentation, users with "Developer" access have the ability to "manage merge requests", but this doesn't seem possible in this case. I have two "Developer" level users that are seeing this problem, one of which pushed the project to the gitlab instance to begin with. I assume he must have write access?

Version information below

```
GitLab 7.14.3
GitLab Shell 2.6.5
GitLab API v3
Ruby 2.1.6p336
Rails 4.1.11
```

Please let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: Can you take a look at the repository settings and see if the branch is fully protected?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Developers can accept merge requests. However, it depends on how the project is configured, too.

Developers can accept merge requests when:

1. The merge target is not a protected branch.
2. The merge target is a protected branch, *if* an owner/maintainer has checked the 'Developers can push' checkbox on the protected branch setting.

If a developer is seeing the message you describe it is probably because of a protected branch and the 'Developers can push' box is unchecked.

Comment: And by default in GitLab, the master branch is protected.

Comment: last i looked, the gui doesn't have a checkbox like you described. see my answer for a potential solution.

Comment: Features in GitLab evolve quickly. Since this response was given for GitLab 7.14 in 2015, it's very likely no longer relevant for the latest versions.

Comment: Still a feature of GitLab 12.0.3, in 2019, as I arrived on this question with the exact same issue. Thanks for the answer @DrewBlessing

Answer (score 14):

As has been stated previously, the developer role is not allowed to merge by default.

[image]

Thus, change the `Settings > Repository > Protected Branches > Protected branch` table where the `Allowed to merge` table cell has the correct role, user, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the Gitlab documentation: "...If you set specific approvers, only they will be able to approve the merge request. If you do not, anyone with developer permission or higher will be able to approve the merge request..."

So, maybe, there is a specific approver for that project.

https://about.gitlab.com/2015/07/29/feature-highlight-merge-request-approvals/

Answer (score 0):

This feature should be available in releases of gitlab >=8.1 where there is an additional "developer can merge" flag/checkbox in addition to 'developer can push'

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/4892

With this in place you may protect the branch (by unchecking 'developer can push') and also allow developer to merge (by checking 'developer can merge')